Streamlit LLM chatbot - Feedback not captured in LangSmith
I'm running a Streamlit app with an integrated LLM chatbot using Langchain, LangSmith and Openai. I'm trying to record a thumbs up feedback in the chatbot after each response from the chain and pass it LangSmith. The thumbs up button is there and works but the Feedback doesn't appear in LangSmith. LangSmith tracking is working as all the runs appear in LangSmith, just the feedback part is missing. Any ideas what could be missing?
import os
import streamlit as st
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFDirectoryLoader
from langchain.callbacks import collect_runs
from langsmith import Client
from streamlit_feedback import streamlit_feedback
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import uuid

# Load environment variables
load_dotenv()

@st.cache_resource
def create_chain():
    llm = ChatOpenAI(model='gpt-4o',temperature=0,openai_api_key=os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'],openai_organization=os.environ['OPENAI_ORGANIZATION'])
    # load documents
    documents = PyPDFDirectoryLoader('x/')
    #text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=2500, chunk_overlap=200)
    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1500, chunk_overlap=200)
    all_splits = text_splitter.split_documents(documents.load())
    # create vector DB
    vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents=all_splits, embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings(chunk_size=1500))

    # Setup memory for conversation
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)

    # Create the RAG chain
    qa_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
        llm=llm,
        retriever=vectorstore.as_retriever(),
        memory=memory,
    )
    return qa_chain

def _submit_feedback(user_response, emoji=None):
    st.toast(f"Feedback submitted: {user_response}", icon=emoji)
    return user_response.update({"metadata": 123})

def handle_feedback_submission():
    feedback = st.session_state.get("feedback_data")
    run_id = st.session_state.run_id
    st.write(run_id)
    st.write(feedback)
    score_mappings = {
                    "": 1,
                    "": 0.75,
                    "": 0.5,
                    "": 0.25,
                    "": 0,
                }

    # Get the score mapping based on the selected feedback option
    score = score_mappings.get(feedback.get("score"))

    if score is not None:
        feedback_type_str = f"faces {feedback.get('score')}"
        try:
            feedback_record = client.create_feedback(
                run_id=run_id, #st.session_state.run_id, # "BG_chatbot",  # Replace with appropriate run ID if available
                feedback_type=feedback_type_str,
                score=score
    #                comment=feedback.get("text", "")
            )
            st.session_state.feedback = {
                "feedback_id": str(feedback_record.id),
                "score": score,
            }
            st.write(f"Feedback recorded with ID: {feedback_record.id}")
        except Exception as e:
            st.error(f"Failed to record feedback: {e}")
    else:
        st.warning("Invalid feedback score.")

client = Client()
chain = create_chain()

# User input for question
if "messages" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["messages"] = []

# Display chat history
for message in st.session_state.messages:
    with st.chat_message(message["role"]):
        st.markdown(message["content"])

user_input = st.chat_input("Stelle eine Frage...")

if user_input:
    st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "user", "content": user_input})
    with st.chat_message("user"):
        st.markdown(user_input)

    # Get the response from the chain
    with collect_runs() as cb:
        response = chain({"question": user_input})
        if cb.traced_runs:
            run_id = cb.traced_runs[0].id
            st.session_state.run_id = run_id
            st.write(f"Run ID: {run_id}")
        else:
            st.error("No runs collected")
            run_id = None

    answer = response['answer']

    st.session_state.messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": answer})
    with st.chat_message("assistant"):
        st.markdown(answer)
    
    # Collect feedback for the response
    if answer is not None:
        feedback = streamlit_feedback(
            feedback_type="faces",
            key=f"feedback_{run_id}"
            #on_submit=lambda: handle_feedback_submission(run_id)
        )
        if feedback:
            st.session_state["feedback_data"] = feedback
            handle_feedback_submission()

